# Who calls prev UIViewController's ViewWillAppear method when we write [self.navigationController popViewController Animated:Yes/No] (IPhone SDK)?

Tags: iphone

Who calls prev UIViewController's ViewWillAppear method when we write [self.navigationController popViewController Animated:Yes/No] ?? (iPhone SDK)

Comment: Your question makes no sense at the moment. Are you able to elaborate a bit further?